# OnBuildBegin and OnBuildProjConfigBegin events of EnvDTE80.DTE2.Events.BuildEvents object not found only when compilation is in Release

Tags: visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-extensions

I created my own Visual Studio Extension that I use the methods `EnvDTE80.DTE2.Solution.SolutionBuild.Clean` and `EnvDTE80.DTE2.Solution.SolutionBuild.Build` to clean and build projects, and also to control when the projects clean or build ends, I add a suscription to this events:

```
EnvDTE80.DTE2.Events.BuildEvents.OnBuildBegin
EnvDTE80.DTE2.Events.BuildEvents.OnBuildProjConfigBegin
```

I was very surprised the different behavior between Debug and Release compliation of the VSIX extension.
When I compile in Debug, the code works fine, even I can debug the code without problems.
But when I run the Visual Studio Experimental Instance from my Visual Studio project in release mode, I have the next error:

> System.MissingMethodException: 'Método no encontrado: 'Void
> EnvDTE._dispBuildEvents_OnBuildBeginEventHandler..ctor(System.Object,
> UIntPtr)'.'

Event I tryed to do this code in Main Thread using the next code, but I get the same error:

```
ThreadHelper.Generic.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    BuildEvents buildEvents = EnvDTE80.DTE2.Events.BuildEvents;
    buildEvents.OnBuildBegin += BuildBeginHandlerMethod;
    buildEvents.OnBuildProjConfigBegin += BuildProjConfigBeginHandlerMethod;
});
```

Any idea or sugestion?

Note: I use Visual Studio 2022 and fails, but I try to do the same Visual Studio 2017 and it works.

Comment: Have you select the suppress JIT optimization on module load?

Comment: I tryped with and without the JIT optimiation and the error is the same. You can see the stack in this image: https://ibb.co/q7KMFGw